# PCA with scikit learn : the iris data example

Tags: scikit-learn, pca

I would like to understand why, in the example "**The Iris Dataset**" on scikit-learn, we cannot recover `X_reduced` from `numpy.dot(iris.data,pca.components_)` (or `pca.components_.T`) 
To my understanding, they should be the same.

thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you ignored any kind of preprocessing.

sklearn has a dedicated API for that, namely [inverse_transform](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.inverse_transform), which [does](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0ab589f/sklearn/decomposition/base.py#L136):

```
    if self.whiten:
        return np.dot(X, np.sqrt(self.explained_variance_[:, np.newaxis]) *
                        self.components_) + self.mean_
    else:
        return np.dot(X, self.components_) + self.mean_
```